# How to align the content with the textbox centrally?

Tags: html, css

I have to complete a combobox to choose the time.
As you can see, the context "from" is not alined to the combobox.

[image]

The HTML code for the two dives are:

```
<div id="fromMessage" style="width:30px;height:100%;float:left;padding-left: 50px;vertical-align:central">
    <oj-label for="Time" style="font-size: 15px">From:</oj-label>
</div>

<div id="seelctTime" style="width:300px;height:100%;float:left;padding-left: 50px">           
    <oj-input-date-time id="Time" value='{{time}}' on-value-changed="{{timeChanged}}">
    </oj-input-date-time>
</div>
```

Why `vertical-align:central` does not work?

Comment: `vertical-align:central` is not a valid value, it should be `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: I tried vertical-align:middle but the "From" is still on top but not middle.

Comment: I created an answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
#idMessage
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%
}
```

in a separate .css file.

top doesn't have to be 50%, just play with percentage til you've got it where you want it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#fromMessage,
#selectTime {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vertical-align method will only work if you use it in a **table** or when the element is an **inline-block** element, but whichever method you use the parent's **height** need to be specified in order for it to work.

The only method which doesn't require height would be using **flexbox**.

There are few ways that you could vertically center element, below is one of the method.

The key things to vertically center are:

- fix height
- absolute positioning
- margin auto
- 0 top value
- 0 bottom value

---

**Example:**

```
    #fromMessage{
      width: 30px;
      float: left;
      padding-left: 50px;
      height: 30px; /*fix height*/
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#fromMessage, #selectTime {
  width:30px;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```